# PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class webhook could not be converted to string

Tags: php, object, fatal-error

My `webhook` class below, along with the test, produces that error.
When I `echo` out `$this->callable_object` it outputs `invoice`, and when I `echo` out `$this->callable_method` it outputs `created`. For some reason this line `return $object->$this->callable_method( $this->event->data );` produces that error and I'm not sure why? It should be the same as `$invoice->created( $args );`

**CLASS + TEST**

```
class webhook {

    private $event;
    private $callable_object;
    private $callable_method;

    private $types = array(
        'invoice.created', 
        'invoice.payment_failed',
        'invoice.payment_succeeded',
        'invoice.updated'
    );

    public function __construct( $event ) {
        $this->event = $event;
        $this->valid();
        $this->parse();
    }

    public function valid() {
        if( !in_array( $this->event->type, $this->types ) ) {
            throw new Exception( 'unknown event' );
        }
    }

    public function parse() {
        $parts = explode( '.', $this->event->type );
        $this->callable_object = $parts[0];
        $this->callable_method = $parts[1];
    }

    public function get_event_type() {
        return $this->event->type;
    }

    public function get_event_data() {
        return $this->event->data;
    }

    public function get_callable_object() {
        return $this->callable_object;
    }

    public function get_callable_method() {
        return $this->callable_method;
    }   

    public function execute() {
        $object = new $this->callable_object();
        return $object->$this->callable_method( $this->event->data );
    }

}

$event['type'] = 'invoice.created';
$webhook = new webhook( (object)$event );
$webhook->execute();
```

Comment: This `$object->$this->callable_method( $this->event->data );` is definitely parsed somehow not what you expect. Try `$object->{$this->callable_method}( $this->event->data );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell php how to parse construct like this:

```
$object->$this->callable_method( $this->event->data );
```

Change to:

```
$object->{$this->callable_method}( $this->event->data );
```

Answer (score 2):

u_mulder is right in his solution, but too explain further...

Here's what you have at the moment: `$object->$this->callable_method( $this->event->data );`

PHP will try to recurse down the properties to `callable_method`, which means that it is looking for a property `$this` on `$object`, and since `$this` cannot be converted to a string, you get an error.

This is basically like in Maths, provided the following `1+1x1+1` the result would be `3`, when we actually mean `(1+1)x(1+1)` which would be `4`. We add the brackets in Maths to add importance (don't shoot me for terminology, you get the idea)

Like in maths, we can do the same with PHP, but we use curly braces instead

`$object->{$this->callable_method}( $this->event->data );`

Comment: Great explanation Lee! Makes total sense now.